# Different definitions of configuration space

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, coordinate-systems, definition

Configuration space has been mentioned in many different areas of physics and from my personal experience I have found the definition has been different from topic to topic.

There are two examples to demonstrate my confusion. In standard lagrangian mechanics, the generalised coordinates span the [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)). For example a particle in a newtonian setting  has a configuration space $Q=\mathbb{R}^3$. The particles trajectory is then a particular curve in this configuration space. The configuration space for this example is finite dimensional.

Now consider classical field theory. We are told the configuration space for a field (with $n$ components) that depends on position and time, $\phi(t,x,y,z)$, is infinite dimensional with each point in configuration space representing a different function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, that is, a particular configuration is an element of configuration space. The feynman functional integral over configurations is a functional integrated over configuration space.

These seem like two different definitions to me. Following the first example then by analogy surely the configuration space would just be $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a particular configuration would be represented by a 'path' (function $f:\mathbb{R}^4$ to configuration space) in said space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *are* different definitions.

Take your *first definition* where $Q=\mathbb R^3$ for a Newtonian particle. According to that, the configuration space in classical field theory per your example is the space of functions
$$
\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^n\,.
$$
So for each point in time $t$, you get a function that depends on the coordinates $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$:
$$
\phi(t,x,y,z)\,.
$$

Of course in relativistic field theory splitting time from space like this is not always convenient, hence your second definition. Perhaps it's best to think of them like this: in the first case, the configuration space is the space of snapshots, while in the second case it is the space of histories.

Answer (score 1):

> For example a particle in a newtonian setting has a configuration space =ℝ3. The particles trajectory is then a particular curve in this configuration space.

Right.  A configuration is a **point** in $Q=\mathbb R^3$, and the particle evolves along a curve $\gamma:t \mapsto \gamma(t)\in Q$.

> These seem like two different definitions to me. Following the first example then by analogy surely the configuration space would just be ℝ and a particular configuration would be represented by a 'path' (function :ℝ4 to configuration space) in said space?

This doesn't make sense to me.  The configuration in point mechanics is an  *element* of $Q=\mathbb R^n$, not a path.  The "trajectory" in field theory is a path $\gamma: t \mapsto \gamma(t)\in Q$ as before, but now $\gamma(t)$ is a field configuration, i.e. a function from $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ (for an $\mathbb R$-valued field, obviously).